# create package for local use only (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

So I wanted to create a package that I can access everywhere on my local machine (using `import`) without uploading it on a package repository like PyPI.

The reason why I'm doing this: I wanted to create an API to access data in the company. Since the data provided was usually not processed, I usually repeated the same process of cleaning and creating dataframes for all sorts of work (ad-hoc, dashboards, etc...).

To do this, I created a local package with an `API` class inside the automatically retrieves data, does the appropriate processing, and returns a `pandas.DataFrame`. The package structure is as follow.

```
/pkg
  /pkg
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

The package works as intended when used inside the directory.

At this point, in order for me to have access to the classes I created inside `main.py`, I used `setuptools`, followed the simple instructions [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and was able to create a wheel file.

I installed my package using `pip` by running `pip install dist\pkg-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl`. Eureka, it works!

I even double checked using `pip freeze` and the package I made is indicated there (`pkg==0.0.1`).

However, when I tried using it on a different directory, `import pkg` doesn't work as intended (returns a `ModuleNotFoundError`).

I have no intention of uploading the wheel file to PyPI (as I mentioned, I only intend to use it within the company as an API to access data for analysis). I'm sure I'm missing something here, I'm not sure what though since this is the first time I've actually created a package like this. How do I do this properly? (or are there any alternative suggestions for doing this?)

Comment: If it's supposed to be used internally, why don't you just append the file to whatever project folder and import it?

Comment: @GRoutar because appending the file to every project I have is redundant. That's no different than copy pasting the same code to scripts on different project directories.

Comment: Try adding a `__init__.py` file in the parent pkg folder. Also, make sure to add the folder path to $PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @gpk27 I've thought of just adding the folder path to $PYTHONPATH but due to this being a work laptop, changing environment variables will require me to pass through the entire process of requesting permission to IT etc...

Creating a wheel file, I thought was a decent alternative especially if there are other people in the org who can use the same package